# Mongodb: Skip collection values from between (not a normal pagination)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I have browsed through various examples but have failed to find what I am looking for.. What I want is to search for a specific document by _id and skip multiple times between a collection by using one query? Or some alternative which is fast enough to my case.

Following query would skip first one and return second in advance:

```
db.posts.find( { "_id" : 1 }, { comments: { $slice: [ 1, 1 ] } } )
```

That would be `skip 0, return 1` and leaves the rest out from result..

But what If there would be like 10000 comments and I would want to use same pattern, but return that array values like this:

```
skip 0, return 1, skip 2, return 3, skip 4, return 5
```

So that would return collection which comments would be size of 5000, because half of them is skipped away. Is this possible? I applied large number like 10000 because I fear that using multiple queries to apply this would not be performance wise.. (example shown in here: [multiple queries to accomplish something similar](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongodb-pagination-using-slice.html)). Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through several resources and concluded that currently this is impossible to make with one query.. Instead, I agreed on that there are only two options to overcome this problem:

1.) Make a loop of some sort and run several slice queries while increasing the position of a slice. Similar [to resource I linked](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongodb-pagination-using-slice.html):

```
var skip = NUMBER_OF_ITEMS * (PAGE_NUMBER - 1)
db.companies.find({}, {$slice:[skip, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS]})
```

However, depending on the type of a data, I would not want to run 5000 individual queries to get only half of the array contents, so I decided to use option 2.) Which seems for me relatively fast and performance wise.

2.) Make  single query by `_id` to row you want and before returning results to client or some other part of your code, skip your unwanted array items away by using for loop and then return the results. I made this at java side since I talked to mongo via morphia. I also used query explain() to mongo and understood that returning single line with array which has 10000 items while specifying `_id` criteria is so fast, that speed wasn't really an issue, I bet that slice skip would only be slower.